# In pub/sub model, how to make Subscriber pause processing based on some external state?

Tags: nservicebus

My requirement is to make the Subscriber pause processing the messages depending on whether a web service is up or not. So, when the web service is down, the messages should keep coming to the subscriber queue from Publisher and keep piling up until the web service is up again. (These messages should not go to the error queue, but stay on the Subscriber queue.)

I tried to use unsubscribe, but the publisher stops sending messages as the unsubscribe seems to clear the subscription info on RavenDB. I have also tried setting the MaxConcurrencyLevel on the Transport class, if I set the worker threads to 0, the messages coming to Subscriber go directly to the error queue. Finally, I tried Defer, which seems to put the current message in audit queue and creates a clone of the message and sends it locally to the subscriber queue when the timeout is completed. Also, since I have to keep checking the status of service and keep defering, I cannot control the order of messages as I cannot predict when the web service will be up.

What is the best way to achieve the behavior I have explained? I am using NServiceBus version 4.5.

Comment: Is the subscriber itself able to check whether the service is online or not?

Comment: Yes, the subscriber can check whether the service is up.

Comment: You can use a saga and timeout if the service is down. and complete the saga once the handler interacting with the web service is complete and replies with a success message. Make sense?

Comment: I did try using a Saga with timeout, but the requirement is to keep checking if the service is up and timeout, how do I achieve this? The message handler gets completed immediately, it does not wait for the timeout handler to return. Hope I am expressing the issue with this approach clearly?!

Comment: You can have a starter handler that checks the web service and then times out for the period you want and then in the timeout handler issue the next time out...

Comment: Another question that should be asked is how likely is it for the web service to be down? If it is uncommon, just let the regular code fail and retry. If it is common (and trying to think out of the box here), how about crashing the process (Environment.Exit(1);) ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to keep trying to handle a message until it succeeds, and not shuffle it back in the queue (keep it at the top and keep trying it)?

I think your only pure-NSB option is to tinker with the MaxRetries setting, which controls First Level Retries: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/msmqtransportconfig.  Setting MaxRetries to a very high number may do what you are looking for, but I can't imagine doing so would be a good practice.

Second Level Retries will defer the message for a configurable amount of time, but IIRC will allow other messages to be handled from the main queue.

I think your best option is to put retry logic into your own code.  So the handler can try to access the service x number of times in a loop (maybe on a delay) before it throws an exception and NSB's retry features kick in.

**Edit:**

Your requirement seems to be something like:

"When an MyEvent comes in, I need to make a webservice call.  If the webservice is down, I need to keep trying X number of times at Y intervals, at which point I will consider it a failure and handle a failure condition.  Until I either succeed or fail, I will block other messages from being handled."

You have some potentially complex logic on handling a message (retry, timeout, error condition, blocking additional messages, etc.).  Keep in mind the role that NSB is intended to play in your system: communication between services via messaging.  While NSB does have some advanced features that allow message orchestration (e.g. sagas), it's not really intended to be used to replace Domain or Application logic.

Bottom line, you may need to write custom code to handle your specific scenario.  A naive solution would be a loop with a delay in your handler, but you may need to create a more robust in-memory collection/queue that holds messages while the service is down and processes them serially when it comes back up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't wanna add retries for the same reason you have mentioned. One thing that did seem to work was to make the current thread sleep, I wouldn't think that's a good practice either.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve somewhat the required behavior is the following:

Define a message handler which checks whether the service is available and if not calls HandleCurrentMessageLater and a message handler which does the actual message processing. Then you specify the message handler order so that the handler which checks the service availability gets executed first.

```
public interface ISomeCommand {}

public class ServiceAvailabilityChecker : IHandleMessages<ISomeCommand>{
   public IBus Bus { get; set; }    
   public void Handle(ISomeCommand message) {
      try {
         // check service
      }
      catch(SpecificException ex) {
         this.Bus.HandleCurrentMessageLater();
      }
   }
}    
public class ActualHandler : IHandleMessages<ISomeCommand>{
   public void Handle(ISomeCommand message) {
   }
}    
public class SomeCommandHandlerOrdering : ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering{
     public void SpecifyOrder(Order order){
          order.Specify(First<ServiceAvailabilityChecker>.Then<ActualHandler>());
     }
}
```

With that design you gain the following:

- You can check the availability before the actual business code is invoked
- If the service is not available the message is put back into the queue
- If the service is available and your business code gets invoked but just before the ActualHandler is invoked the service becomes unavailable you get First and Second Level retries (and again the availability check in the pipeline)